# What is the purpose of Solenoid Valve in Reverse Osmosis? Can I do away with it?

Tags: plumbing, filter, water-filtration

The SV (36v) in my RO water purifier has stopped working. Product is currently unavaiable in [Amazon](https://www.amazon.in/Moxie-Solenoid-Valve-Water-Filter/dp/B07F3MP1DT) and with the lockdown in effect in my city, I'm not even able to get a replacement.

So I was wondering if I can simply bypass it (remove the blocking pin that gets sucked in to allow flow of water) as the flow is currently blocked because of the SV not working.

My only concern is about the consequences of that action....what would happen if the water flow is not blocked by the SV?

Comment: You may be able to bypass it with a manual valve but manufactures don’t install components that are not needed. You would need to know when to use the bypass if possible.

Comment: Can't tell you the purpose of a particular valve without a diagram, but the process of reverse osmosis involves a good deal of flushing things off the filter membrane under automatic control.

Comment: Did you check to see if the SV can be fixed?  Perhaps it's just plugged with some debris and if you clean it out it will work again?

Comment: @jwh20 Yeh, I opened it. Seemed all clean to me. Perhaps the coil inside has been cut off at some stage.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the fact that Amazon is no doubt delighted that you think they are the *only* place to order stuff online, **they are not.**

I would suggest expanding your online vendor search considerably.

And no, unless you somehow know when the valve should be actuated and do so at those times, and **only** those times, "simply bypassing it" can be clearly described as "simply breaking your RO filter differently than it's broken now."

Comment: But but but... the person has PRIME!  Surely you can't suggest paying for shipping! :)

Comment: The problem is that with the COVID-19 situation, online vendors are only delivering essential supplies (groceries) currently. The shops are closed too owing to lockdown, so this is the worst possible time for the SV to break down.

Comment: Not my experience at all. Hardware is being classed "essential" (some "decorative" items are non-) and gets delivered.